# iOS Keyboard Return Handler

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to Mac, iOS, Xcode and objective-c.  I am very familiar with the Windows world (.net, C#, Silverlight, etc), but none of that really applies to what I am doing here on the Mac.

So in short I am hoping that you would help me out with pointers and a code review of sorts.  There are many articles on the web (many of those on stack overflow) and you can easily get lost in all the opinions of how to do things.

So I decided to try a few simple things, like making the iOS keyboard react to Next and Done, show a toolbar above the keyboard and make text fields move to allow room for the keyboard.  First sample I have here is the simple one, three text fields, two with Next and the last with Done to close the keyboard.

[image]

I added UITextFieldDelegate and a IBOutlet for each text field to the header file.  Also Ctrl-dragged the text field onto the IBOutlet to connect it.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField* firstNameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField* lastNameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField* cityTextField;

@end
```

In the source file I added the synthesize statements for the text fields, the set to nil in the viewDidUnload to flag the memory for release (using the auto memory release mode) and the textFieldShouldReturn method to set the focus on the text fields.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize firstNameTextField = _firstNameTextField;
@synthesize lastNameTextField = _lastNameTextField;
@synthesize cityTextField = _cityTextField;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setFirstNameTextField:nil];
    [self setLastNameTextField:nil];
    [self setCityTextField:nil];

    [super viewDidUnload];    
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField
{
    if (theTextField == self.firstNameTextField)
    {
        [self.lastNameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (theTextField == self.lastNameTextField)
    {
        [self.cityTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
@end
```

Is this how you would do this?

From an objective-c perspective, would you put the * (for pointer) with the type or in front of the name?

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField* firstNameTextField;
```

vs.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstNameTextField;
```

Is the memory management correct?  Will the memory be released correctly, stay alive etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anthony stated, the position of the asterisk is really a concern of style. Personally I prefer the * on the side of the instance (Class *classInstance) because it's the instance that you're pointing to, not the class. But opinions differ.

In general, the code is fine, except for that you've defined all your properties as weak. Because you want to retain these IBOutlet properties for the life of your view controller, they should be strong. Even though you've constructed your views in IB, your view controller still 'owns' those IB objects.

When you define a property type as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AClass *aClassInstance;
```

That means your object will be retained when it's assigned. In this case, the assignment happens by virtue of having wired your outlets, you don't assign manually, but the retain still occurs:

```
[self setProperty:object] //retains 'object'
```

And released when you nil it:

```
[self setProperty:nil] //releases 'object' currently retained by property
```

And if/when (as you have done) you do actually want a weak property (eg, to have a reference to an object you don't own):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic)
```

You wouldn't be required to "release" it later by setting it to nil in your viewDidUnload. Setting it to nil would still be good practice, but not required to balance your memory.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I got the weak keyword from one of the examples on the Apple web site, was not sure which to use though.  So the actual TextField control lives in the storyboard, gets attached to the property via the UI, but the variable lives for the duration of the ViewController. Seems fair enough.

Comment: I will make the changes and run it again.  Still have to figure out what tools to use in the Apple world to see if my app closed correctly without any memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Where the `*` goes is going to either be defined by you if you're the sole developer, or a coding standard if you're working in a group> Just stay consistant.

I didn't look through things for memory, but you may want to look into `UITextField`'s `inputAccessoryView` property. You can assign a `UIView` such as a `UIToolbar` to that property. In the toolbar, add a `next`, `previous`, and `done` button. This gives a behavior similar to how many other applications - Such as saffari - do things such as this.

Comment: Seems most of the objective-c examples have the star next to the instance as you said.  I am a solo developer, so my rules are all mine. :-)  Just curious what others think.  Ages ago when I used C/C++ I used to put the * next to the type.  My argument was that it's a char* pointer called foo, the type of the variable bring char*.

Comment: I always put it by the type because I see it as part of the type name.